# Chrome DevTools: Loop through NodeList

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

On a page, I have a table with multiple rows (mostly 100), each having multiple columns. Every row has an anchor with the class `.no-red`.

I am using chrome dev tools console to fetch this anchor element using

```
document.querySelectorAll('.no-red')
```

This returns me an array

```
NodeList(100) [a.no-red.selectorgadget_selected, 
a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, 
a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, 
a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, 
a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, 
a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested, a.no-red.selectorgadget_suggested
....and so on]
```

I want to loop inside this list and extract the text of each anchor element.

Here's a sample of one anchor element

```
<a class="no-red selectorgadget_selected" ng-href="https://www.twitter.com/java" target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com/java"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> java</a>
```

How do I get the text of all the 100 anchor elements?

Comment: yout can try something like this `var list = document.querySelectorAll('.no-red')
var stringmap = list.map(x => x.textContent)`

Comment: Thanks @Gotrank. Where do I type this? I am using Google Console.

Comment: If you write this to the console you will have a variable which contains a string list about the text of elements.

Comment: I did. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var.

Comment: @CuriousDev - you'll need the semi-colons between statements if you're not going to put them all on their own line. Thus, you'll need 1 and should use 2 of them. One at the end, the other after the `querySelectorAll` call. ;)

Comment: I tried that too. Uncaught TypeError: list.map is not a function

Comment: `(1)` $$('.no-red').map(e => e.textContent) `(2)` copy($$('.no-red').map(e => e.textContent).join('\n')) //to copy to clipboard

Comment: @CuriousDev make the results of `querySelectorAll` an array first like this `var entries = Array.from($0.querySelectorAll('li'))`. Then call `map` on this array.

Answer (score 4):

Building on wOxxOm's answer.

To select the text content (the text in between the HTML tags) of an element whose CSS class name is 'no-red'

```
<a class="no-red">My Text</a>
```

First, open the Chrome Developer Tools by either clicking on the right-hand menu with the dots in Chrome, then click More tools and then Developer Tools, or use the key combination Ctrl+Shift+I

Next, click on the Console tab

Type at the flashing cursor,

```
$$('.no-red').map(e => e.textContent)
```

This will extract the text content of the corresponding element with a class of 'no-red'. But it won't make it available to you to do anything else.

If you are attempting this operation in order to extract the text and then copy and paste into some other application or code then you can type the following at the cursor to select the text you need and copy it to the clipboard from where you can change to your program/software of choice and paste from the clipboard using the Edit > Paste menu item, or Ctrl+V key combination

```
copy($$('.no-red').map(e => e.textContent).join('\n'))
```